# VueJS - How to have a mark/ticks for every 10 units of the slider

Tags: vue.js, slider, range

I am trying to display the slider of 100 units. Currently, I am displaying the 100 units slider with 100% width, the code below shows how I have done it:

```
<input type="range" :min="0" :max="100"  v-model="high" style="width:100%">
     <span id="high_value"><div class="value" v-if="high"> {{high + '%'}} </div></span>
     ...
     high: '20'
```

Here is the slider that I am displaying:

[image]

I want to display my slider something like this:

[image]

As you can see in the image, the round or dot-like is present for every interval, I am looking to display my slider similarly. I want something effective way to do it, I tried using the CSS but it was not looking so good.

I want the rounded/dot-like for every 10 units.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i found out the answer myself, we can have mark/tick in sliders by using CSS and then placing them in every interval.

But effective way is, we can use a **vue-slider** component which has many features and we can display colorful sliders.

https://nightcatsama.github.io/vue-slider-component/#/

There are three themes :

- default - It comes up with the normal colors and looks simple.
- antd - It comes up with the gradient colors and looks are super.
- material - It is styled between the default and antd.